# Upgrading product catalog created in Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 to Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We are in a process of upgrading Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 instance into Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.1.

We have a custom plugin and two catalogs with lots of categories and products.

I have already seen this [community thread](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/8765) where some folks mentioned that upgrade between these versions is not supported.

Is there a possibility to at least migrate product catalog between these versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can migrate you Commerce Server Catalog to XC9.

First of all, you need to extend Catalog system entities schema [link](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/083614)

Detailed instruction you can find [here](https://websterian.com/2018/05/11/sitecore-commerce-9-x-showing-custom-product-attributes-on-the-product-details-page-using-sxa/)

After that, you can implement your custom plugin in XC9 and and call there Commerce Server Service API for get catalog structure/data. Use XC9 Engine API for create the same catalog in SC9.

Look at Postman Collections (Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK), which Sitecore team provides OOTB. You can find there all examples of requests to SC Engine.

When your catalog will be created in XC9, you can use Postman request for export you catalogs. Also you can create your custom environment and add there some pipelines which will create catalog base on your exported catalog during `InitializeEnvironment` your custom environment.

As an example, you can look at `Plagin.Sample.Habitat` project.

Comment: I am new to Sitecore Commerce and need the step by step process for Upgrading from Sitecore Commerce 8.1 to Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1.The answer provided here was not very helpful as I need a detailed steps of what need to be done and steps to consider, tools to used, how to move data and Prerequisites etc